# jQuery selectors being temperamental

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I just learned jQuery over the last two days, so I'm kind of new to this.

I'm trying to build a simple navigation sidebar.  I built the bars as tables, and when the user goes over a specific cell, that cell lights up and another sub-navigational bar appears next to the original bar.

The original bar appears immediately below the header.  So the syntax I used was:

```
var headerHeight = $('#headerTable').height();
$('#selectStart').offset({left: 0, top: headerHeight});
....
<table id="selectStart" class="selector1">
    <tr><td id="sel1Projects" class="selector1">
....
```

So far, so good.  Now I want to make it so that when the user clicks on a  in that table, the corresponding sub-navigational bar appears immediately to the right of the first navbar.  So I wrote two new tables to test it:

```
<table id="selectProjects" id="table2" class="selector2" class="table2">
<tr><td id="sel2Project1" class="selector2">
....
<table id="selectDevelopment" id="table2" class="selector2" class="table2">
<tr><td id="sel2Dev1" class="selector2">
```

But the selectors for these are being a real pain in the neck.  When I just do

```
var select1Width = $('#selectStart').width();
$('#selectProjects').offset({left: select1Width, top: headerHeight});
$('#selectDevelopment').offset({left: select1Width, top: headerHeight});
```

It works perfectly; however, this isn't very good coding - I should be grouping all the similar tables so that I can position them all the same way, and then only show the one that I want the user to see at the time.

```
$('.selector2').offset(...)
```

works fine as far as selecting all the tables, but it also puts all the s in the same spot, since they all share the same class for styling purposes.  So far, however, this is all what I expected.

```
$('.selector2 table').offset(...)
```

I expected this to just select the tables in that class.  It didn't do anything.  Is there a problem with the way I'm typing it?
After some frustration, I added the second class, "table2", to each of them.

```
$('#table2').offset(...)
```

Still nothing.  So I added the new class for them

```
$('.table2').offset(...)
```

Nothing; however, using the other class they share, selector2, does work.  And it can't be an issue of not needing to select the tables, because when I selected the tables individually, I got the desired result.

So what am I doing wrong and what am I not understanding?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Maybe you need this: $("#selectProjects #sel2Project1")? Note that you shouldn't use the same id for more than one element.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to select the <td> elements.  I want to align the tables properly, but jQuery isn't letting me select them as a group - just individually.

Comment: I notice your tables each have two `class` attributes. I don't think that's valid. If you want to add an extra class, add it to the existing `class` attribute but separate it from the previous one with a space.

Comment: One id per element ONLY.  And all id values must be unique in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $('.selector2 table').offset(...)

try this

$('table.selector2').offset(...)

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  So what was wrong with the things I was trying before?

Comment: ```.selector2 table``` gives you children of elements with the selector2 class that are tables. ```table.selector2``` gives you tables that have the selector2 class.

Answer (score 0):

You cant repeat id for jquery...see if changing it solves your prob

Comment: Deleting the "table2" id from them didn't do anything.

Comment: how about combinning the classes?